# ¿Cómo detener un hilo?

Tags: java, netbeans, hilos

Tengo un programa que al pulsar un botón, empieza a realizar acciones en segundo plano mediante un worker. Lo que quiero implementar es un botón de cancelar, de forma que al pulsarlo, se detenga el hilo. He usado thread.interrupt() asociado al botón cancelar, pero este no hace nada y no entiendo porque. El método thread.stop() está deprecated, por lo que preferiría evitar usarlo.

```
// Worker que realiza tareas en segundo plano y evita que se congele la interfáz gráfica
// loader y thread están creados más arriba
        SwingWorker<Void, Integer> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Integer>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception { 
                loader = new PDFDivideLoader(fileInput);
                thread = new Thread(loader);
                thread.start(); 
                /**
                 * Código irrelevante
                 */
                            
                // Mientras el hilo siga ejecutandose, el bucle se repetirá
                while (thread.isAlive() == true) {
                    /**
                     * Código irrelevante
                     */  
                }

                return null;
            }
            
            @Override
            protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
                /**
                 * Código irrelevante
                 */
            }
            
            @Override
            protected void done() {
                /**
                 * Código irrelevante
                 */
            }
        };


// Listener del botón cancelar
private void buttonCancelarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                           
        thread.interrupt();
        actionButtons(true);                  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detener hilos en Java ha sido algo confuso desde los inicios de la plataforma. El mecanismo que debemos usar es **interrupt** y nuestro código (sea cual sea) debe chequear frecuentemente si hay un **interrupt** y ahí decidir si procesarlo o lanzar una excepción para que otro código decida qué debe hacer para concluir esta tarea y no dejar nada pendiente.

En tu código particular debes depender en que los que hayan escrito `PDFDivideLoader` estén procesando correctamente los interrupts. Si lo hicieron correctamente tu hilo se detendrá. Sino, en realidad no hay una muy buena forma de detener el hilo.

---

A continuación una explicación más detallada de qué deberia hacer `PDFDivideLoader` y otro código ante un interrupt. Basado en mi respuesta aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904072/java-difference-in-usage-between-thread-interrupted-and-thread-isinterrupted/62438836#62438836.

**¿Por qué interrupt?**

Interrumpir hilos en Java es util cuando tienes una tarea que va a correr por un largo rato pero luego decides que debe detenerse, o cuando tienes un daemon que necesitas apagar, entre otros ejemplos.

**Cómo interrumpir**

Para interrumpir debes llamar interrupt() sobre el hilo. Esto es un proceso colaborativo, así que tu código debe estar listo para esto:

`myThread.interrupt();`

**Código Responsable**

Tu código tiene la responsabilidad de estar lista para cualquier interrupción. Iría tan lejos que diría que en cualquier ocasión que tengas una tarea que ejecuta por mucho tiempo deberías insertar código como este:

```
while (... algo largo...) {

     ... haz algo largo

     if (Thread.interrupted()) {
         ... detén lo que estás haciendo...
     }
}
```

**¿Cómo detener lo que estás haciendo?**

Tienes varias opciones:

Si estás dentro de `Runnable.run()` simplemente retorna o haz un break de tu bucle y completa el método.

Ej:

```
   public void run() { 
     try {
       while (true) {
           ... hacer algo largo
           
           // detecta una interrupción
           if (Thread.interrupted()) {
               // me interrumpieron, me detengo
               break; // o return;
           }
       }
     } catch (IOException ex) {
       // sucedió un error
       return;
     }
   }
```

Pero tal vez estés en otro método bien dentro del código, tal vez en una clase más general. En tal caso tal vez tiene más sentido solo lanzar `InterruptedException` para que simplemente se interrumpa la ejecución (dejando la bandera de interrupted falso).

Pero tal vez profundo dentro de tu código no tiene sentido lanzar `InterruptedException`. En tales casos lo que podrías hacer es lanzar otra excepción pero también marcar el hilo como interrumpido para que se pueda detectar posteriormente que estamos en proceso de interrupcíon:

```
private void algunMetodoBienProfundo() {
    while (.. tarea bien larga .. ) {
          ... mucho trabajo...

          if (Thread.interrupted()) {
             // oh no! una interrupción!
             Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
             throw new SomeOtherException();
          }
     }
}
```

Ahora la excepción puede propagarse y tener la alternativa de interrumpir el hilo o ser atrapado, pero  esperemos el código que está procesando la excepción eventualmente se dará cuenta que una interrupción está en proceso.

**Debo usar  isInterrupted() o interrupted()**

Deberías preferir interrupted() por que:

1. Tu código debería dejar en blanco la bandera interrupt del hilo porque si no lo haces el hilo en el que está podría ir al thread pool con un estado interrumpido causando problemas (claro, eso sería un error del código del thread pool), no tendrías problema con  `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` por ejemplo. Pero otro código de pools podría tenerlo.
2. Liberando la bandera de interrupted indica que has recibido el mensaje y que estás tomando acción. Si lo dejas prendido, después de un rato el que llamó el interrupt puede suponer que no respondiste al llamado en un tiempo razonable.

**¿Por qué interrupt()? ¿Por qué no usar otra bandera propia en mi código?**

Interrupt es el mejor mecanismo para interrupción porque es lo que las librerías de Java utilizan. Por tanto todo el código puede ser sensible a ello.

Si encontramos código que está solo haciendo el catch e ignorando **InterruptException** o no chequeando `interrupted()` entonces podemos corregir esos errores y hacer que el código siempre pueda interrumpirse sin crear dependencias raras o mecanismos no estándares en nuestro código.

Desgraciadamente Joshua Block propuso lo opuesto en su famoso libro *Effective Java, Second Edition*. Pero usar `interrupt()` de la forma estandar es mucho mejor.

**¿Pero no es que Future.cancel() ya maneja esto?***

Future.cancel() saca la tarea de la cola de ejecucieon. Si tu tarea ya está corriendo, no lo detendrá. Entonces cancel() es un concepto distinto que interrupt. Como dice el Javadoc:

> Attempts to cancel execution of this task. This attempt will fail if
> the task has already completed, has already been cancelled, or could
> not be cancelled for some other reason. If successful, and this task
> has not started when cancel is called, this task should never run. If
> the task has already started, then the mayInterruptIfRunning parameter
> determines whether the thread executing this task should be
> interrupted in an attempt to stop the task.
> https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)

Pero llamar Future.cancel() si generaré un **interrupt** si **mayInterruptIfRunning** es verdadero.

Answer (score 1):

El método `thread.interrupt()` no siempre detendrá inmediatamente el hilo en ejecución, ya que solo establece una bandera de interrupción en el hilo. Por lo tanto, es necesario verificar regularmente si la bandera de interrupción se ha establecido y actuar en consecuencia en el hilo. Puedes hacer esto llamando al método `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` en el hilo y comprobando su valor.

Puedes modificar el bucle while para que verifique si la bandera de interrupción está establecida y salga del bucle:

```
try {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && thread.isAlive()) {
        // código irrelevante
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // manejo de la excepción de interrupción
}
```

Debes agregar un `try/catch` en caso de que se produzca una excepción de interrupción en el hilo, lo que puede ocurrir al llamar al método `interrupt()`.

Comment: Genial, lo implementare. Solo una duda rápida... ¿Hay alguna forma de "retirar" el interrupted() del hilo? No sé si me explico correctamente... Porque si vuelvo a poner thread.start() se ejecutará otra vez ¿no? Gracias.

Comment: Una forma es simplemente ignorar la interrupción llamando al método `Thread.interrupted()` en el hilo afectado. Esto limpiará el estado de interrupción del hilo, de modo que cualquier llamada futura a `interrupted()` devolverá false.

Comment: No es claro el uso de interrupted() aqui ni tiene sentido el catch aquí. Mi respuesta de abajo lo explica en mucho más detalle.